# Security concern - web browser control as UI and all logic contained within client side application

Tags: c#, html, mysql, security, webkit

My apologies if this does not adhere to the 'type of questions' policy though I believe this to be somewhat answerable.

We use: **C#.NET4**, **WebKit.NET** and **MySQL**

We're developing a C#.NET4 with WebKit.NET as the UI (a WinForm with the WebKit browser control). All HTML is defined within application - the only thing being pulled externally is what is in the remote MySQL database.

The C# in the application right now handles all the events in the webkit browser control. Essentially it steps in upon certain events, accepts the values of user input (if applicable) and performs work.

I believe this to be risky because it's not like its connecting to an instance of PHP on an external server - all the "server" like work is happening locally within the application on the clients computer. If someone was able to break the application (reverse engineer it?) the whole methodology is revealed (usernames, passwords, table names, etc).

In desktop applications, is it common for there to be a partner like application that sits on the server, accepts data and then connects to the MySQL server on the behalf of the client-side program?

Perhaps I am being paranoid but all eggs in the client side basket makes me afraid.

Comment: Check out XKCD http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: You shouldn't put stuff a hacker shouldn't know in a client-side application. Try opening a compiled file in notepad(++), and notice it contains a LOT of plain text strings. You can hide it a bit, but it will be recoverable in the end.

Comment: Indeed. So I need to have some sort of middleman that accepts the input and dictates what sensitive information is passed back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only put validating logic on the client side, it will be easy to bypass it. The obvious example would be websites that only validate in javascript on the client side: disable javascript and you can insert anything you want.

If you put any connecting db passwords hardcoded in the client, anyone will be able to just access your database, if they reverse-engineered the application. Packet sniffing and watching open connections is also a great way to find out details.

If there is any kind of user accounts involved, I'd implement it like this:

1. Users log in on a client
2. Client sends login credentials to the server application. The client can validate input, but mostly for just helping the user and speeding up the process. Use SSL for the server, otherwise passwords will be interceptable. Validate the certificate to make sure it is *your* server, and you immediately get rid of Man in the Middle attacks.
3. Server rejects all invalid inputs, performing its own input validation, and otherwise performs the database operations you want it to, returning the results. This way you keep your database access regulated. It might also return a session auth thing, to allow further requests. Alternatively the connection might just stay open. I would not make it return the database password to allow direct interfacing: this could be extracted from a running application using debugging tools.
4. client accepts and parses the results, life continues.

Comment: Point blank clear. Thank you for helping the newcomer. I was so disgusted by the setup of the project I did not want to continue until I had this part clear.

Comment: Making server-side code perform the data manipulation operations is also a great way to make sure only those operations are permitted.